# How to insert data to mysql database from android via wireless LAN?

Tags: android, mysql, wifimanager

i want to insert my text field value into MYSQL database from android via wireless LAN. I have wireless LAN connection. My database is in my laptop. I run my android app into another laptop. Both laptop are connected to wireless LAN.

How do i pass/insert the data into my database via wireless LAN. I use WAMPsever2.0.

-Thanking you.

Comment: If your application is connected to database you can do whatever you need. First check for the connection.

Comment: We need more specifics. Are you asking how to trouble shoot your network connectivity? Are you unsure how to develop an Android app that connects to an external MySQL database? Are you asking how to write an INSERT statement?

Comment: @AgRizzo i already inserted my data into my database. But how will i send my data to database via wireless LAN? i mean to say is there any logic or any method to send data over wireless LAN to my database. I have already connected my android app to MySQL database and also inserted the data into the database. Is there any method or function that can send data to database over wireless LAN?